# How do ISS astronauts keep proficient on capsule procedures in long duration missions?

Tags: iss, procedure, training, capsule

Before astronauts and cosmonauts go to the ISS they have months of simulator training on Soyuz spacecraft procedures for launch, rendezvous, docking and re-entry. Yet, once  they are on the ISS they are up there for weeks, often many months before coming back. As a pilot myself I know how skills can erode without practice.

How do astronauts/cosmonauts keep current on re-entry procedures and remain familiar with the spacecraft controls? Are there any training aids on the ISS?

As a second part to the question will this be done differently with the commercial spacecraft being developed?

Comment: I'd be shocked if they don't have detailed checklists to be followed.

Comment: That's not really what I'm asking @CarlWitthoft, it's about keeping familiar with controls. As far as I know there's no simulator up there.

Comment: Astronauts on the ISS use virtual reality on board for EVA training: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20140000406.pdf. I wonder if something similar could be done for flight training?

Comment: Is there a training mode of the Soyuz spacecraft? If Soyuz is powered down, some switches may be fliped without effect.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the monthly ISS report in BIS's SpaceFlight magazine regularly mentions training, so that might be a place to look. ISTR Soyuz does, as Uwe suggests, have a training mode (but probably only since the upgrade to "modern" computer controls)